# Adobe Edge Stage Name

Tags: animation, adobe, adobe-edge

I am having issues in Adobe Edge CC 2014. How can I change the Stage ID so that I can have multiple animations on the one web page? I am doing all of this in asp.net and am pulling my hair out.

My animation would play and then I have an update panel that has C# codebehind to adjust the CSS to play a different animation based on a query.

When I put the below code in, it places 1 of the animations correctly then shows me the second one but it's all at the top of the page and really large. I believe the issue is that they are both set at "Stage" in the animation and I need to have 1 as Stage1 and the other as Stage2 somehow.

Please tell me how I can accomplish this in adobe animate.

```
`<div id="StageA" class="SECONDTRAIN">
                        </div>
                        <div id="StageB" class="FirstTrain">
                        </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"    
     src="TrainAnimates/SecondTrain/SecondTrain_edgePreload.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
     src="TrainAnimates/FirstTrain/FirstTrain_edgePreload.js"></script>
<style>
     .edgeLoad-FIRSTRAIN{display:none;}
     .edgeLoad-SECONDTRAIN { display:none; }

     #StageA, #StageB
     {
         position:absolute;
         left:10px;
         top:10px;

     }

     #StageA
     {
         display:none;
     }

</style>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe nesting compositions could help instead of different Stage id-s.

http://edgedocks.com/content/2013/12/nesting-animate-compositions-composition-loader-edge-commons